# chrome screen sharing with audio support using jssip

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, screensharing, jssip

I have tested webrtc screen sharing and Its working fine with both firefox and chrome, I have a question about screen sharing with audio.

using jssip on firefox I simply added "audio: true" to MediaConstraints and it works fine but in case of chrome I can’t use audio with screen sharing at the same time (chrome returns media access denied) here is my firefox mediaConstraints:

```
const firefoxMediaConstraints =
{
    audio : true,
    video : {
        mediaSource  : 'screen',
        width        : 480,
        height       : 360,
        maxFrameRate : 10
    }
};
```

How can I add screen sharing with audio on chrome?

Comment: So you are able to have the MediaStream from "screen" without the audio on chrome? If I'm not mistaken, that means you are using an extension right? If so, I never tried that myself, but do you also have access to an *usual* LocalMediaStream, e.g one coming from the microphone only? If you can, then you could try doing both in parallel, then merge the videoTrack of your screen stream with the audioTrack of your mic stream (either `new MediaStream([track1, track2])`, or `stream1.addTrack(track2)`... But of course, that's a lot of `if` to pass beforehand...

Comment: @kaiido Thanks for your feedback, yeah I need something similar but there is no way to use jssip api I guess, If you worked with jssip library, can you tell me how we can add it to jssip?

Comment: Ah no I never worked with jssip, are they able to make the screen-sharing call in Chrome? They claim zero plugin, but IIRC, Chrome only accepts screen-sharing from `chrome://` scripts (i.e extensions).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do two separate getUserMedia (or in the future, one getUserMedia and one getDisplayMedia) calls, one audio-only and another one for the screensharing. Then add the resulting tracks together into a new MediaStream (or add the screensharing video track to the audio-only stream)

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is needed in latests Chrome versions in order to acquire the media devices.